# Jenkins execute a job from work space instead of SVN path

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-3

I want to trigger a `Jenkins` job for a `maven`(v3.5.3) project from my local work space folder location instead of configuring SVN Repository URL in the Source code management section. Is there a way to achieve this?. I need to test with code modifications in the project and not wanting to commit the changes, that is the purpose.

I am using Jenkins (v2.161) and it is installed in another machine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What about local builds with Maven, why don't you want to build the project locally to test it before committing? That should be done usually and normally.

Comment: I am triggering a `Sonarqube` analysis from Jenkins. So I am trying to induce some bugs in the source code to check if the report is generating properly for the bugs accounted. This is for double checking purpose to make sure it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it might look like a sort of tinkering, the source code can be pulled to the Jenknins' host from your local machine, provided that they are properly configured to communicate via ssh.

In the project build configuration on Jenkins' host:

Do not use "Source Code Management" (choose "None").

Check "Delete workspace before build starts", to avoid conflicts with previous changes.

As the very first build step, add "Execute shell" and write a few commands that pull the data, for example:

```
scp myusername@myhost:/path/to/myworkspace/myproject/src .
scp myusername@myhost:/path/to/myworkspace/myproject/pom.xml .
# etc for all the files/dirs you need to build the project
```

Then continue with the build steps that were already used for building the project from SCM.